# How can I unblock Font in Angular App - CORS error

Tags: angular, localhost, cpanel

When attempting to load a font into my Angular app I get the following error:

> Access to font at
> 'http://www.wdw-demo.co.uk/raleway-regular-webfont.woff' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

The font is hosted on my own webspace which is managed with cPanel. Is there anyway I can make this file public though file manager in cPanel and available to localhost?

Comment: I think you should set up a CORS policy on the server hosting the font to allow access from any domain. Specifics on how to go about implementing this will be dependent on the type of webserver, programming language and/or framework you are using for your server.

Comment: How Can I do that with cPanel?

Comment: Adding a CORS header to your .htaccess file should fix the issue. More here: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-enable-cors-on-apache-in-whm.409452/post-2300871

Comment: Thank you - that fixed the issue for me